there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
I'm trying to install this 4chan clone: https://github.com/Ro0ul/4Chan-Clone
I'm executing one of the queries on the sql folder on phpmyadmin:
CREATE TABLE comment(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    posted_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    image_src VARCHAR(255),
    board VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(post_id)
        REFERENCES post(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)

But I get the error: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
How can I fix this without changing much the table (because like I said I want to install that 4chan clone)

id sure looks like it should be a key.

This question is similar to: Phpmyadmin #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As far as I know only PostgreSQL can do auto-increment in columns that are not the  primary key. If you are using MySQL that auto-increment column MUST BE the primary key.

@TheImpaler MUST BE the primary key , MUST BE indexed is the proper term as I have linked the MySQL docs on my answer , even if it 'acts' like a primary key since the records are unique.

@ErgestBasha I didn't know. You are right fiddle.

You can define column id as PRIMARY KEY
CREATE TABLE comment(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    posted_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    image_src VARCHAR(255),
    board VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(post_id)
        REFERENCES post(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Test it here

From CREATE TABLE Statement

There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be
indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value

In simple terms AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows. And it is a perfect candidate for PRIMARY KEY.


How can I fix this without changing much the table (because like I
said I want to install that 4chan clone)

Add PRIMARY KEY after AUTO_INCREMENT
Better would be
CREATE TABLE comment(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    posted_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    image_src VARCHAR(255),
    board VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES post(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

